# Is it possible two share a class loader in two apks which share the same process space in android?

Tags: java, android, classloader, native

Consider the following:
We have two projects/apks which share the same process space (this is possible in android using a shared process id, which you can add in your android manifest). Is it possible to use the same instance of a class loader in both apks/projects?
The problem I want to overcome is that when having two seperate class loaders every apk will have its own copy of a class defined in a certain java library. I want them to share the exact same class, because otherwise every class will load a shared library which is loaded statically. This will result in loading a shared library more than once and finally in a crashing application.

Comment: Did you find an answer?